# export 'useHistory' (imported as 'useHistory') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs

this is the error code i get each i run my project on a browser:

export 'useHistory' (imported as 'useHistory') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_useBlocker, unstable_usePrompt, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Clearly `useHistory` doesn't exist in `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 1):

`useHistory()` is deprecated now. use `useNavigate()` instead .

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

//use it liek this
navigate('/route_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

We get this error because the useHistory() hook has been replaced by the useNavigate() hook in react-router-dom v6. We need to change the useHistory hook to the useNavigate hook. The useNavigate() hook returns a function that allows us to navigate between pages programmatically.

To solve this we can use,

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
```

we import ‘useNavigate’ instead of ‘useHistory’ because React Router version 6 changed the ‘useHistory()’ hook to ‘useNavigate()’.  All that is going on is a button that will be clicked to navigate from our Home Page.

For more details, you can go here https://reactjsguru.com/usehistory-was-not-found-in-react-router-dom/

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Now, we use `useNavigate()` instead of `useHistory`, to move from one page to another in react, & have to just import `useNavigate` from react router `dom`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

To fix this error, you need to replace useHistory with the useNavigate hook. Because that will return a function that allows you to navigate programmatically. Example const navigate = useNavigate().
below is an example to fix the error

```
// ️ import useNavigate Here instead of useHistory
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    // Now you can navigate programmatically to other pages using navigate
    navigate('/');
  };
 
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Navigate to Home</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```